# Send EvenService Remix

Tags: remix.run

I am using the remix Send Event Service and I have the event instance like this = import { EventEmitter } from "events";

export const emitter = new EventEmitter(); and if I put the emitter.on and emitter.emit in the same component it works fine for me, the problem is when I separate them it is as if another instance of the event was created and it doesn't work for me

That no instances of the event are repeated and that it works fine even if I broadcast it from a place other than where I turn it on